# The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, windows-update, io

A few weeks ago something bad happened to my OS (Windows 10). In my laptop I have SSD with OS and HDD for data (cd drive slot).

I usually hibernate my PC instead of shutting it down. I also have a bad habit of postponing system updates for a few days.

After ~2 "ask me later" Windows somehow updates the system anyway (I hibernate my PC, next day I run it and I see it restarted and updated - not sure how and when this happens, but that's not so important).

Whenever it updates and restarts on it's own - my HDD gets an I/O device error.

## Facts:

- The drive is present in "This PC"
- Sometimes I can create a file on that drive (and add some content to it)
- I cannot open any file which was created before restart (files get opened by programs, but cannot be displayed - some app-specific errors)
- I can open some directories (different path depths), but most cannot be opened
  [image]
- **Disconnecting and cleaning HDD connection does not help**
- **Restarting OS does not help**

## The only way to fix it is to:

1. Turn off PC
2. Remove HDD
3. Start OS <------- starting OS **without** HDD is absolutely crucial
4. Turn off PC again
5. Connect HDD again
6. Start OS
7. HDD works perfectly until next Windows update

Based on the workaround above, I believe the problem is **not** hardware related. The question is can I fix it permanently without reinstalling the OS?

## Windows Events logs:

Nothing interesting except lots of such Warnings:

```
The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. Corruption may occur in VolumeId: D:, DeviceName: \Device\HarddiskVolume7.
(The I/O device reported an I/O error.)

- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs" Guid="{3FF37A1C-A68D-4D6E-8C9B-F79E8B16C482}" /> 
  <EventID>140</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>3</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000008</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-01-23T21:07:23.058660400Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>27166</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="4308" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>gisek</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="VolumeId">D:</Data> 
  <Data Name="DeviceName">\Device\HarddiskVolume7</Data> 
  <Data Name="Error">0xc0000185</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: Any relevant errors being logged in the Windows Event log?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Added logs to the question

Comment: This really looks like a hardware related problem, cabling, the device itself, etc. However, to rule out software you could try clean booting Windows when the drive is misbehaving to see if that helps.

Comment: Any new developments with this problem? I may be in a similar situation.

Comment: @Philip actually yes. See the answer.

Comment: Less than ideal, but still a solution I suppose :) Your initial workaround did resolve my IO errors, probably temporarily. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to [refresh](https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/refresh-windows-10-without-losing-programs-4348.html) Windows. I chose the option "Keep personal files, apps and Windows settings", which left my files and programs intact. After that problem has never occurred again.